# Calculating maximum power such that result is within limit

Tags: c#, exponential, pow

I'm currently working on an exponential falloff (http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/02/26-handle-transient-errors-in-c/) implementation.

I'm calculating the delay to wait, such that:

```
var delay = (int) Math.Round(Math.Pow(timeBetweenAttempts, attempt), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Obviously, this delay starts to get very large, very quickly, even with the time between attempts being 10 milliseconds.

I would like to be able to do something akin:

```
var maxTimeBetweenAttempts = 5000; // 5 seconds is the hard limit
var nominalTimeBetweenAttempts = 10;

var maxNumberOfAttempts = // calculate the maximum number of raises that would hold below 5000.
```

Obviously this could be calculated using a loop, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why not just use a `Math.Min(delay, maxTimeBetweenAttempts)`?

Comment: Instead of `pow(x, n)`, you need a family of delays `s * pow(x / s, n)`.  The largest acceptable `n` can be determined by `log(maxdelay / s) / log(x / s)` which is also `(log(maxdelay) - log(s)) / (log(x) - log(s))`.  In fact, you already do have the scaling factor, implicitly chosen by your preferred unit.  10 milliseconds and .01 seconds are the same length of time, but if you did `pow(.01, n)` you would find the delays get *shorter* as `n` increases, not longer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Because that doesn't solve "delay will get large very quickly".

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of exponentiation is logarithm so you can use that.
You would use

```
if (attempt < Math.Log(maxTimeBetweenAttempts) / Math.Log(nominalTimeBetweenAttempts))
{
    Retry(++attempt);
}
```

To see if the attempt was below the threshold after rounding.

However, as this requires an extra calculation and is a little less obvious (as it uses logarithmic maths that most people haven't event seen since school) than just doing the exponential, I would personally recommend just calculating the power and testing that.

ie.

```
if(Math.Pow(nominalTimeBetweenAttempts, attempt) < maxTimeBetweenAttempts)
{
    Retry(++attempt);
}
```

**Edit:**

Re-reading your question, you explicitly state that you want to know the maximum number of retries before they reach a certain length. That would be:

```
var maximumNumberOfAttempts = Math.Floor(Math.Log(maxTimeBetweenAttempts) / Math.Log(nominalTimeBetweenAttempts))
```

Comment: It looks like that didn't answer your question. What am I missing?